# Posting linkedIn using access_token via php guzzle

Tags: php, http-post, linkedin-api, guzzle

I am trying to post a link on Linked using `LinkedIn Share API` using `access token`via `PHP GUZZLE`.
Below is my code.

```
    $client = new GuzzleHttp\Client(['base_uri' => 'https://api.linkedin.com']);
    $access_token =  'AQWJ0aksdlfjhadfsjjfksasdfasfdHBIJvTUGa_t_3FvaqZPnrsMACC-JyPvpL2GBANlOMLUBSK8OEyfUl9_VLoxVe4ACBePysj-_WHv1-PP-Q-xas2owrngUtlq9P7Z2o95XUiO-Xhd9y0bm36DX9JXyxW-3jV2uBwP9pLJDC_FRZQ2JiCE';
    $req = $client->request('POST', '/v1/people/~/shares?format=json', [
                'headers'           => ["Authorization: Bearer " . $access_token . "\r\n" . "x-li-format: json\r\n" ],
                'client_id'     => '77g514g0o223322v44',
                        'client_secret' => 'iXadQhy2323jpzPbz7Js',
                'json'      => [ 'json' =>[
                                'comment' => "Check out developer.linkedin.com!",
                                'content' => [
                                        "title" => "LinkedIn Developers Resources",
                                        "description" => "Leverage LinkedIn's APIs to maximize engagement",
                                        "submitted-url" => "https://developer.linkedin.com",  
                                        "submitted-image-url" => "https://example.com/logo.png"
                                        ],
                                'visibility' => ['code' => 'anyone']
                                ]
                            ]
            ]);
    var_dump($req->getStatusCode());
```

But it is always giving me `Unauthorized response` with `401` code.

I know, I am doing wrong some where. Any help where I am getting wrong..

Answer (score 1):

below is code how I solve my problem, hope it will help others as well.

```
$body = new stdClass();
$body->comment = "Check out https://github.com/faisalahsan";
$body->content = new stdClass();
$body->content->title = "Test ABCasdfadsf";
$body->content->description = "My Open Source Contribution";
$body->content->{'submitted-url'} = "https://github.com/faisalahsan";
$body->content->{'submitted-image-url'} = "https://avatars0.githubusercontent.com/u/8427383?v=3&s=460";
$body->visibility = new stdClass();
$body->visibility->code = "anyone";

$body_json = json_encode($body, true);

$client = new GuzzleHttp\Client(['base_uri' => 'https://api.linkedin.com']);
$access_token =  'AQWJ0bPoW9VpPrEYWvywLk2cx1fhwysjaadsfjja#fsExHBIJvTUGa_t_3FvaqZPnrsMACC-JyPvpL2GBANlOMLUBSK8OEyfUl9_VLoxVe4ACBePysj-_WHv1-PP-Q-xas2owrngUtlq9P7Z2o95XUiO-Xhd9y0bm36DX9JXyxW-3jV2uBwP9pLJDC_FRZQ2JiCE';

$req = $client->request('POST', '/v1/people/~/shares?format=json', [
        'headers'           => ["Authorization" => "Bearer " . $access_token,
                    "Content-Type" => "application/json",
                            "x-li-format"=>"json"],
        'client_id'     => '77gasdfkjo22v44',
                'client_secret' => 'iXadQ123askdfzPbz7Js',
        'body'      => $body_json
    ]);
var_dump($req);
die;
```

Comment: Thanks, Your code helped me figure out how to make calls to linkedin using guzzle.

Comment: Note: JSON can be passed using the 'Json' option in lieu of 'body' so no need to json_encode first. https://guzzle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/request-options.html#json